# Retrieve Followed sites of Office365 group team sites

Tags: office-365, client-object-model

i have below code to fetch the followed sites of my online and its working fine ..but when i am trying to retrieve the office365 group sites... this code doesn't return me those sites..

Any suggestions to retrieve the team sites followed by me under office 365 group.

any help will be appreciated ..

below is my code `CCPortal.Home.FavoriteSites = (function () {
          'use strict';

```
      var results, iLimit = 0;;
    function InitFavoriteSites() {
        $('#pnlFavoriteSites').text("Favorite Sites");
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {                               
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getFavoriteSites, "sp.userprofiles.js");                                 
        });
    }      

    function getFavoriteSites() {

        var favArr , siteJson,follow, allSitesJson = [], FavoriteStar;
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var followingManager = new  SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);
        var documents = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();
        documents = followingManager.getFollowed(4);  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

            documents.forEach(function (doc, i)
            {
                var item = {};
                item.Name = doc.get_name();                    
                item.url = doc.get_uri();
                follow = 'CumminsIconFav Star';                    
                siteJson = ({ Title: doc.get_name(), URL: doc.get_uri(), Html: follow});                  
                    allSitesJson.push(siteJson);
            });          
            $scope.Favsites = allSitesJson;
            $scope.fnUnfollowSite = fnUnfollowSite;
            $scope.$apply();
            $('#pnlFavoriteSites').text("Favorite Sites");                            

            if (allSitesJson.length == 0) {                  
                $("#divFSErrorMsg").html("<span style='font-size:16px;display:block'>You are not following any site.</span><span style='display:block'>Following a site makes it easier to find it. Simply click the star icon on any site to start following it</span>")
            }
            if (allSitesJson.length > 20) {
                $("#seeAllDiv").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#seeAllDiv").hide();
            }

        }

        , function (sender, args) {
            console.log("Error: " + args.get_message());
        });       
    }`
```

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible using OOTB SharePoint REST/JSOM APIs.

However, you can make use of the undocumented REST API endpoint `/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed?mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=100&fillSiteData=true` to fetch data about followed sites. This endpoint gives you both, classic and modern, followed sites.

Since this is undocumented and unsupported, please be careful while using it as it may stop at some point in the future. FYI - this endpoint is also used in the `/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` page to show these sites.

**Usage**:

**Using jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed?mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=100&fillSiteData=true",
  type: "GET",  
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  success: function(data){
    //do some stuff with data
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

**Using AngularJS 1.6.x**

```
var req = {
 method: "GET",
 url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed?mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=100&fillSiteData=true",
 headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" } 
}

$http(req).then(function(data){
    //bind values from data to html
    console.log(data);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Reference - [Following O365 sites](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Following-O365-Sites-API/td-p/45348)

Comment: This works, however, the endpoint returns the recent visited sites, not the followed office365 team sites, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look to the [Microsoft Graph API documentation, if you go to the "sites"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-follow?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) related v1.0 reference, you will notice you can perform a query like the one below:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/followedSites`

That query will return the followed sites for the current user. After that, you could apply some filtering based on if such sites are "o365 teams site" or some other type.